# Take user input to navigate to a directory

Tags: python

So how to make python take user input so that it can navigate to the file directory  the user has given it. The File name `ede.html` will always be the same but depending on every user the directory to the file keeps changing.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)?

Comment: well I've not worked a lot with it, thus could you explain a little more ?

Comment: If I run a script using `python script.py`, when it gets to `raw_input` it will wait for user input. So if you had `user_in = raw_input('Location of ede.html: ')`, it would prompt the user with "Location of ede.html: " and store whatever the user entered into `user_in`. You can then use that to navigate appropriately. Be careful though - executing arbitrary files can be dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, I modified my existing script with your code, works like a charm now !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change a directory like so

```
import os
os.chdir('../dir')
```

As for user input, you can try getting it with `raw_input`and checking it's validity with the methods in the `os.path` module.

Comment: Could you please explain a little more, I mean I want the user to type in their directory and then I want python to execute the file the ede.html in that directory

Comment: Cools finally figured out raw_input.